# How can you select a number of paramters from an array in JavaScript (jQuery.path)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to animate specific HTML elements based on a number of clicks the user makes using jQuery.path.
The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure of the best way to select the parameters that are relative to the chosen element.

Here is my current code:

```
    var segment1Params = {
       start: {
          x: 414,
          y: 121,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      }

    var segment2Params = {
       start: {
          x: 494,
          y: 104,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      }

    var segment3Params = {
       start: {
          x: 420,
          y: 306,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      }

    var segment4Params = {
       start: {
          x: 514,
          y: 389,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      } 

    var segmentSelected = 1;

    $('body').click(function () {
        segmentSelected += 1; //the amount of user clicks
        $("#segment-"+segmentSelected).animate({path : new $.path.bezier(segment1Params)})
        if (segmentSelected == 5) {
            segmentSelected = 1; //reset the amount of user clicks (looping)
        }
    });
```

Ideally I would want the line...

```
$("#segment-"+segmentSelected).animate({path : new $.path.bezier(segment1Params)})
```

...to select the correct set of parameters.

I am thinking this can be done with an array but syntactically I am unsure on the best approach.

Comment: Yep, whenever you have variables with a counter in them, using an array or object instead would be better. Arrays are explained in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the segments into one array and use a function that takes a segment number as an argument and performs the animation.

Note the `segments[sid-1]` - this is because in DOM it appears your segments start with 1: `#segment-1`, `#segment-2` and so on, but array elements always start by default from 0.

Another thing is initializing `segmentSelected` with `0`: this is because this variable is supposed to mean how many times the user clicked on the `body` element, and initially this says "0 times" before any clicks happen.

```
var segments = [{
       start: {
          x: 414,
          y: 121,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      },
     {
       start: {
          x: 494,
          y: 104,
          angle: 358.156,
          length: 0.300
        },
        end: {
          x: 114,
          y: 121,
          angle: 0.229,
          length: 0.704
        }
      } ... ];

       var segmentSelected = 0;

       function animateSegment(sid)
       {
                  $("#segment-"+sid).animate({path : new $.path.bezier(segments[sid-1])});
       }

       $('body').click(function () {
        segmentSelected += 1; //the amount of user clicks
        animateSegment(segmentSelected);
        if (segmentSelected == 5) {
            segmentSelected = 0; //reset the amount of user clicks (looping)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array similar to this:

```
var selectedSegment = 1;
var segments = [];

segments.push({
    start: {
        x: 414,
        y: 121,
        angle: 358.156,
        length: 0.300
    },
    end: {
        x: 114,
        y: 121,
        angle: 0.229,
        length: 0.704
    }
});

segments.push({
    start: {
        x: 494,
        y: 104,
        angle: 358.156,
        length: 0.300
    },
    end: {
        x: 114,
        y: 121,
        angle: 0.229,
        length: 0.704
    }
})

segments.push({
    start: {
        x: 420,
        y: 306,
        angle: 358.156,
        length: 0.300
    },
    end: {
        x: 114,
        y: 121,
        angle: 0.229,
        length: 0.704
    }
})

segments.push({
    start: {
        x: 514,
        y: 389,
        angle: 358.156,
        length: 0.300
    },
    end: {
        x: 114,
        y: 121,
        angle: 0.229,
        length: 0.704
    }
})
```

Then use it like this:

```
console.log(segments[selectedSegment]);
```

---

#### Side-Note

---

I'm using [**array.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) in the example above which adds a new element ot the **end** of the array.

To add an item to the beginning of an array use [**Array.unshift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead.